# To write work capacity of heart by symbols?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, work, flow

I know that the work capacity of the heart is

```
Work capacity of the heart = pumping capacity x aortic impedance.
```

I would mark work by W and impedance by Z.
However, I am not sure how to mark the pumping capacity.

I think the units of W are joules and of impedance Ns / m.
So pumping capacity m / s^2. 
I think something wrong, since does not feel right.

I think the units of pumping capacity should be m^3.
So aortic impedance is N/m^2, which is the same as Pressure.
Aortic impedance should not be the same as pressure.

My problem is to understand the word capacity.
Normally, I relate energy per temperature unit with it but here I cannot.

**How can you write this sentence with correct units?**

Comment: What are the units of `W` and `Z`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this were a mechanical pump, then the work done per unit volume pumped would be:

$$ W = VP $$

where $V$ is the volume pumped and $P$ is the pressure increase across the pump.

According to Wikipedia the volume pumped per heartbeat (at 72 bpm - does it change with pulse rate?) is about $70$ cubic centimetres per beat, which is $7 \times 10^{-5}$ m$^3$. The normal systolic blood pressure is $90 - 120$ torr, which is $12,000 - 16,000$ Pa - take $14,000$ as a convenient figure. Then the work per beat is:

$$ W = 7 \times 10^{-5} \times 14000 = 1 J $$

That's a bit puny - 1.2W at a resting pulse rate. That's barely enough to run my smartphone.

Comment: Why they use the word impedance? I agree that your equation must hold, but I do not understand the sense of giving such a equation as in the question.

Comment: I wouldn't attach too much significance to the terminology. The word *impedance* has a precise meaning in electronics, but more generally I suspect it's just taken to mean resistance, or in this case pressure i.e. Newtons per square metre. I assume *pumping capacity* is cubic metres per second, or per beat or per whatever unit you want.